# Doxygen - How to link to the Modules page

Tags: doxygen

How do i link to the modules page where all groups are listed?

I know i can link to `modules.html`, but this will not work if i create a format other then html (e.g. PDF).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [alias](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) for something like this:

`\htmlonly<a href="modules.html">link</a>\endhtmlonly \latexonly\hyperlink{...}\endlatexonly`

The problem is that the `\Chapter{Modules}` does not have an attached `\label`. Maybe you can reference the first module, since the module's individual pages provide labels.

I have not tried it for other output formats.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What shoud i put in for `...`? There is no `\Chapters` or `\label` command. Linking to the first module will give me the Groups description page which does not help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell you. I am not that deep into Latex. Doxygen does not output a \label for the Modules chapter. Maybe there is way to reference a Chapter without a label in Latex. I don't know how to do this.